# Typeahead.js error

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am having a problem in my code,i need some help?I didn't know may be the error in remote section.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'users.php?query=%QUERY'
  });

  users.initialize();

  $('#users').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
  }, {
    name: 'users',
    displayKey: 'username',
    source: users.ttAdapter()
  });
});
```

Comment: What error? I didn't see nothing. Please add error text.

Comment: I have fixed the error

Comment: So, where was the error, share.